Reactjs useState not replacing previous state
I have a component that loads all products on component load. The component also has a search functionality that takes user input and querys database for products based on user input. Search results should replace any products that were initially loaded by the component. Below is the load and search functionality.
The problem I am seeing is that the search function does not replace the loaded products, but it appends any products returned by the search to the already load product list.
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [limit] = useState(100);
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadProducts = async () => {
      console.log('Fetching products for page:', page);
      try {
        const data = await fetchProducts(page, limit);
        console.log('Fetched products:', data);
        setProducts(prevProducts => [...prevProducts, ...data.products]);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error fetching products:', err);
      }
    };
    loadProducts();
  }, [page, limit]);

  const handleSearch = async () => {
    console.log('Searching for products with query:', searchQuery);
    try {
      const data = await searchProducts(searchQuery);
      setProducts(data.products);  
      setPage(1);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error searching for products:', err);
    }
  };


why not simply setProducts( data.products )? why do you HAVE to mix them with prev state?

The issue arises because the setProducts call in the loadProducts function appends new products to the existing list.
To ensure that search results replace the loaded products, you need to modify the useEffect hook to clear the products array before fetching new products when a search query is present:
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [limit] = useState(100);
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadProducts = async () => {
      console.log('Fetching products for page:', page);
      try {
        const data = await fetchProducts(page, limit);
        console.log('Fetched products:', data);
        if (searchQuery) {
          // If there is a search query, replace the products with search results
          setProducts(data.products);
        } else {
          // Otherwise, append new products to the existing list
          setProducts(prevProducts => [...prevProducts, ...data.products]);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error fetching products:', err);
      }
    };
    loadProducts();
  }, [page, limit, searchQuery]);

  const handleSearch = async () => {
    console.log('Searching for products with query:', searchQuery);
    try {
      const data = await searchProducts(searchQuery);
      setProducts(data.products);  
      setPage(1);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error searching for products:', err);
    }
  };


setPage(1) causes page state to change. Since page changes and a re-render happens, the first useEffect runs (because it is included in the dependency). In the first useEffect products are appended - setProducts(prevProducts => [...prevProducts, ...data.products]);.
The first useEffect callback also fetches products, based on pagination I think. We probably want to check if page number is 1 and queryString is not empty, then we do not need to run the first useEffect logic. Use an if condition.
If page is 1 and queryString is empty you might want to run the effect because I assume that is how you load more data.

Hi  Tushar. Not "the first useEffect". Instead the effect invokes its callback again because it has invoked it already on first render. Forgive my nitpicking, I just feel that I should tell you than having someone else do whatever.

The issue is You are using setPage(1) after the setProducts(data.products); inside the handleSearch method.
This setPage(1) agin trigger the useEffect and call the  loadProducts method

What you can do is create a generic method that accepts both page limit and searchQuery when the searchQuery is null it will return the paginated data

maintain a single useState to keep track of the products.
